# Loop not functioning for digit counter

Tags: c

So i have this piece of code and even though i enter 16 digit numbers it will simply loop back infinetly, can someone help me?

```
if (!strcmp(tropos,"card")){
    do{
        printf("dose noumero kartas me akrivos 16 psifia\n");
        scanf("%lld",&cardnum);
        no=cardnum;
        while(no!=0){
            no /= 10;
            ++totalDigits;
        }
    } while(totalDigits!=16);
}
```

Comment: Please show the definitions of `cardnum` and `no`. Regular `int`s cannot represent 16-digit nummbers.And your logic won't work for numbers with leading zeros.

Comment: Both are long long

Comment: This would fail the condition and then forever: 
Input: 1234, 123456, 12384*, 45**

At * = 15, at** = 17, and never 16

Comment: Change it to `while(totalDigits<16);` as this will stop as soon as it either reaches 16 or goes above it.

Comment: problem is i need to test if the cardnum has exactly 16 digits. It also has a problem whenever a digit is a 0

Comment: The card number is more like an id, so why don't you read it in as string? That would probably make the verification easier and the user could enter it in the usual way as blocks of four instead of one long chunk.

Comment: Yes - you should definitely read a string - check string length and every char by isdigit().

Answer (score 3):

```
do{
    totalDigits = 0; // you need to reset totalDigits every time you retry!
    printf("dose noumero kartas me akrivos 16 psifia\n");
    scanf("%lld",&cardnum);
    no=cardnum;
    while(no!=0){
        no /= 10;
        ++totalDigits;
    }
} while(totalDigits!=16);
```

This solution has problems if there are leading zeros. For example `0000123412341234` will count only 12 digits. My suggestion would be to use the input as a string to check if the number of digits is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont know how to count digits in a string.

Comment: You can `#include <string.h>` and use the function `strlen(str)` which will return the length of the string. [Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/)